PYTHON / FLASK / JS error when sending Jsonified data - SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
So, I have a flask server that sends me these variables:
    responseAPI = {
        "data": detection_data["Race"],
        "gender": detection_data["Gender"],
        "age": detection_data["Age"],
        "job": most_probable_job,
        "jobAlternatives": Job_alternatives,
        "raceAlternatives": Race_alternatives,



    }   
    responseAPI = jsonify(responseAPI)
    return responseAPI

On JS I capture them using:
window.onload = () => {
    console.log("hello");
    const res = fetch ('http://localhost:5000/deepface', {mode: 'no-cors'}).then( async (res) => {
        let r = await res.json();
        console.log(r);
    });
   
}

However, when it reaches the part of res.json it displays me a SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input. I've tried a lot of alternatives that keep displaying this error to me. When I don't try to force it as a json the error doesn't display, but I need in Json
The reason why I need them as json it's because, later, the idea is to push them into the front end using js

The "no-cors" option is almost certainly the problem; it's literally telling the browser to ignore the response.

Oh gosh, yeah this was the problem - thank you so much!

As Pointy answered in the comment section, the answer was the "no-cors" changed the mode to cors
    console.log("hello");
    const res = fetch ('http://localhost:5000/deepface', {mode: 'cors'}).then( async (res) => {
        let r = await res.json();
        console.log(r);
    });
   
}

And added headers to the server response
 responseAPI = jsonify(responseAPI)
    # status 
    responseAPI.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    return responseAPI

